# Control calls on physical phone from PC software

Tags: windows

Looking for a solution to place calls programmatically from a Windows PC to a connected physical phone.

Final result should be that pressing something in the PC should place a call on a connected physical phone. Not calling with VOIP and also not using the PC audio and mic for the phone call. I need just to send a command from the PC that will place the call without the need to dial the number manually.

This is for a company that calls hundreds of numbers every day for delivery proposes.

Comment: This sounds like a software question unless you're looking for a specific PC that comes with a phone line jack? Do you need the hardware to actually get a PC to connect to a phone line? Or just the way to use a PC to dial numbers?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't clear whether this is a request for hardware or software. See comment above. The question can be re-opened if it's edited for clarity & on-topic.